# Where does $\pi(x)^{\frac{1}{\ln(x)}}$ reach a height of $e$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I am trying to solve the equation:$$\pi(x)^{\frac{1}{\ln(x)}}=e.$$

Originally I was trying to calculate $$ \lim_{x\to \infty} \pi(x)^{\frac{1}{\ln(x)}}, $$ but from my calculations the limit goes to infinity. That means the function in question must reach $e$ at some point. I know that $x^{\frac{1}{\ln(x)}}=e,$ and therefore, $\pi(x)^{\frac{1}{\ln(\pi(x))}}=e.$ This tells me again that the function is greater than $e$ at some point.

So what is the solution? I know the number must be very large.

Comment: $\log \lim_{x \to \infty} \pi(x)^{1/\ln(x)} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\log \pi(x)}{\log x} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\log \frac{x}{\log x}}{\log x} = 1$, so the limit is $e$.

Comment: Oh I guess I did the limit calculation wrong, I realize my mistake now

Comment: $\pi(x)^{1/\log(x)}=e\implies\pi(x)=x$, which is never true since $\pi(x)\lt x$.

Comment: So the limit as x approaches infinity of the prime counting function raised to the derivative of the logarithmic integral is $e$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

${2n \choose n} = {2(n-1) \choose n-1}\frac{2n(2n-1)}{n^2}$ and $\log n! = \sum_{p^k \le n}\lfloor n/p^k \rfloor \log p$ means

$$n \log 4 = O(\log {2n \choose n}) = O(\sum_{p^k \le n}(\lfloor 2n/p^k \rfloor-2\lfloor n/p^k\rfloor) 
\log p) = \sum_{p^k \le n} O(\log p) = O(\pi(n) \log^2 n)$$

Together with $\pi(n) = O(n)$ we obtain $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log \pi(n) }{\log n} = 1$$